# Can I write images to system album more than 5 times?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am very puzzled on this matter that I can only write image to system album 5 times.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

I got this log if the value of i equals to 5:

> *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL

I did not find any related information about 5 times from the API document .
Well... Can I write images to system album continuously more than 5 times? Is it too fast to write to system album ? Is there another way to do it ?

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: You can, but I don't see why ever you would want to do that.

Comment: How? I just want to export a lot of images user selected from my app to system saved album.

Comment: Have you tried it with _different_ images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

image is an autoreleased variable. I assume you're not using ARC. Will it still fail if you retain it first and then release it after the loop?

EDIT:  How about if you put your call in a delayed method, i.e.:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myUIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum:) withObject:image afterDelay:0];
```

where you've also defined:

```
- (void) myUIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum:(UIImage *) image {
   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Your writes may just need to go through the run loop after each attempt.

Comment: I'm using ARC. Yes, it would still failed.

Comment: Thank you ,Owen .But it still failed.

Comment: Does it still fail if you set the delay to be the value of i? (i.e. first time through delay 1 second, the second image 2 seconds, third image 3, etc.